# Getting unwanted escaped xml tags in output file

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xslt-1.0

XSLT transform using Visual Studio 2010 and in C#.
I'm in need of help.  I am getting different output depending on how I do the transform.
Running the transform in the VS debugger I get the following output.  Notice the non-escaped tags.

```
<Service_Log>
<row>
      <EntryNumber>00</EntryNumber>
      <ErrorID>B004</ErrorID>
      <ErrorDate>2/06/2007 18:06:07</ErrorDate>
      <ErrorInfo>00000000</ErrorInfo>
      </row>
<row>
...
</Service_Log>
```

When I run the transform in C# using the following code snippet I get output with the xml tags escaped - and I don't want them escaped.  What am I missing?

```
XslCompiledTransform trans = new XslCompiledTransform();
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
string fname = FixPath(WorkingFolder) + "Phase1.xml";
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fname, settings);
trans.Transform(xmlFile, writer);


&lt;readsym_Service_Log&gt;
&lt;row&gt;
      &lt;EntryNumber&gt;00&lt;/EntryNumber&gt;
      &lt;ErrorID&gt;B004&lt;/ErrorID&gt;
      &lt;ErrorDate&gt;2/06/2007 18:06:07&lt;/ErrorDate&gt;
      &lt;ErrorInfo&gt;00000000&lt;/ErrorInfo&gt;

      &lt;/row&gt;
&lt;row&gt;
...
```

Comment: Technically, it's invalid XML if the data contains a backslash that is not escaped.

Comment: The data contains forward slashes in the date field.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean... sorry for the confusion.  Maybe that's throwing off the transformation.

Comment: I just added code to wrap date fields in CDATA blocks.  So it's not that.

Comment: BTW:  The xml output from the debugger session passes xml validation with no errors.    http://www.xmlvalidation.com

Comment: Can you post the xslt and the xml files you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
        string inputFileName = @"XMLFile1.xml";
        string xsltFileName = @"XSLTFile1.xslt";
        string outputFileName = @"XMLFile2.xml";


        XslCompiledTransform trans = new XslCompiledTransform();
        XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings();
        settings.EnableScript = true;
        trans.Load(xsltFileName, settings, null);

        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(outputFileName);

        trans.Transform(inputFileName, writer);
```

Comment: I tried that code.  Had to make some changes to get it to compile but still get the same escaped output.